# How can I select multiple copies of the same row?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access with rows which have a column called "repeat"

I want to `SELECT` all the rows, duplicated by their "repeat" column value.

For example, if repeat is 4, then I should return 4 rows of the same values. If repeat is 1, then I should return only one row.

This is very similar to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608143

Except I need a solution for MS Access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create a "Numbers" table and fill it with numbers from 1 to 1000 (or up to whatever value the "Repeat" column can have):

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers
  ( i INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ) ;

INSERT INTO Numbers 
  (i)
VALUES
  (1), (2), ..., (1000) ;
```

then you can use this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TableX AS t
  JOIN
     Numbers AS n
       ON n.i <= t.repeat ;
```

Comment: +1, Answer will be accepted except that your code is not valid MS Access SQL. You need parenthesis around the the table and the join condition.

Comment: Actually, for the join condition in Access you don't need parens. For the `insert into ... values ...` though you do need to insert one value at a time, since Access doesn't support the multi-insert syntax.

Comment: If you want a lot of numbers in your numbers table, you can simplify by creating the table with `CREATE TABLE numbers ( i INT IDENTITY)` and then do the inserting with `DECLARE @i int = 0;
WHILE @i < 1024
BEGIN
 SET @i = @i + 1;
 INSERT INTO numbers DEFAULT VALUES;
END;`  Obviously you can change the 1024 to whatever number you want.  In my case I wanted 1 to 1024 in the table.

Comment: @DylanSmith does Access have `IDENTITY`? If I remember well, it calls them differently.

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  I don't think it does.  I was thinking SQL Server.  Never mind then!

Comment: @DylanSmith and it was just an example/pseudocode, to show that the table has to be filled. There are different ways to do this, depending on the DBMS and the number of rows you want to fill. (for a billion rows for example, I wouldn't use the WHILE loop ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ what would you use for a billion rows?

Comment: @DylanSmith probably a cross join of some sort. Take a table of 1000 rows (which you can easily get in SQL Server with a simple `SELECT TOP (1000) rn = ROW_NUMBER() FROM sys.all_objects;` ) and cross join it to itself 4 times, for example. (see the various answers here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183062/how-to-ensure-contiguity-of-a-tally-table ) In Postgres, there's the `generate_series()` function that produces a number table on the fly so it doesn't need a number table at all.

Answer (score 1):

If repeat has only small values you can try:

```
select id, col1 from table where repeat > 0
union all
select id, col1 from table where repeat > 1
union all
select id, col1 from table where repeat > 2
union all
select id, col1 from table where repeat > 3
union all ....
```

Comment: I have repeats up to 85 times.... but this code should work. It will be an ugly query though :D

Comment: Access won't allow a query as long as I need.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to retrieve the one 'unique' row and copy this row/column into a string however many copies you need from it using a for loop.